# Error when trying to install virtualbox-5.1

Tags: linux, virtualbox, cuckoo

I'm trying to install Cuckoo (Ubuntu 64 bit) the commands that worked are:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git -y

$ sudo apt-get install python python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev -y
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-setuptools -y
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev swig -y

$ sudo apt-get install mongodb -y
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev -y


$ echo deb http://http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
$ wget -q https://https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib"
$ wget -q https://virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

and when I executed the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1 -y
```

I got the following error:
[image]
Any help please on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you downloaded the .deb package from the website rather than using apt.

Comment: could you give me the link please?

Comment: @Daniel K, Sure! I would recommend to wget the link using the terminal. An example is 'wget <link>'. Here it is: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.12/virtualbox-6.0_6.0.12-133076~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb After you finish downloading, you can type in 'dpkg -i <package name>' to make Ubuntu automatically install your package. Before doing any of this I would suggest updating your system using 'sudo apt-get udpate && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help.